# R dplyr purrr find index value of column minimum across multiple columns and corresponding row value at index

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataset of air pollution values each which corresponds to a particular station. I've computed the number of nulls for each air pollution variable and station code. Now I want to find the station for each pollutant with the minimum number of nulls.

Here is the dataset:

```
nulls_by_code
# A tibble: 34 x 9
   code    nox   no2    o3   so2    co pm10_raw  pm10  pm25
   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int> <int> <int>
 1 BL0    7195  1386  1234  4933 24408    24408  2981  2092
 2 BQ7     240   240   229 24392 24392      310   326 24392
 3 BQ8   24296 24296 24296 24296 24296    24296   323 24296
 4 CR8   24395 24395 24395 24395 24395    24395 24395   733
 5 CT3    1055  1055 24393 24393 24393     2365   971  2888
 6 EI3    1994  1994 24283 24283 24283    24283  3801 24283
 7 EN7     271   271 24392 24392 24392    24392 24392 24392
 8 HG4     205   205  1048 24392 24392    24392 24392 24392
 9 HP1   24391  8610  9596 24391 24391    24391  7987  8255
10 HP3   15633 15633 15633 15633 15633    15633 15633 15633
# … with 24 more rows
```

I've read a few posts about similar problems, but they're not quite what I want. There is no grouping variable in my data and I want to compute the minimum and the corresponding code for every column, something like:

```
nulls_by_code %>% 
     summarise(across(nox:pm25, ~ slice(which.min(.)))) %>% 
     mutate(across(nox:pm25, code)) ## I know this won't work, not sure which verb to use!
```

I've looked at:
[Find Minimum of a column and corresponding row of the minimum with condition on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654181/find-minimum-of-a-column-and-corresponding-row-of-the-minimum-with-condition-on)
and [minimum (or maximum) value of each row across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193433/minimum-or-maximum-value-of-each-row-across-multiple-columns)
and [How to select the row with the maximum value in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group) but none of these have got me to dplyr dataframe nirvana.

The result should look something like this, or a transpose version of to ensure that columns have the same datatype and don't mix  and .

```
+-----------+-----+-----+------+------+
| row_name  | nox | no2 | pm10 | pm25 |
+-----------+-----+-----+------+------+
| min_value | 205 | 205 | 323  | 733  |
| min_code  | HG4 | HG4 | BQ8  | CR8  |
+-----------+-----+-----+------+------+
```

I suspect dplyr grandmaster @akrun will be able to fix this in 10 seconds ... :-)
Thanks for any help you are able to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to long format via `tidyr::pivot_longer` and making use of `dplyr::top_n` this could be achieved like so:

As you want the minimum values for each pollutant we first group by `pollutant` and get the one row cointaining the minimum value per group by making use of `top_n(1, -value)` where `value` is a default name assigned by `pivot_longer`.

```r
nulls_by_code <- read.table(text = "code    nox   no2    o3   so2    co pm10_raw  pm10  pm25
  1 BL0    7195  1386  1234  4933 24408    24408  2981  2092
2 BQ7     240   240   229 24392 24392      310   326 24392
3 BQ8   24296 24296 24296 24296 24296    24296   323 24296
4 CR8   24395 24395 24395 24395 24395    24395 24395   733
5 CT3    1055  1055 24393 24393 24393     2365   971  2888
6 EI3    1994  1994 24283 24283 24283    24283  3801 24283
7 EN7     271   271 24392 24392 24392    24392 24392 24392
8 HG4     205   205  1048 24392 24392    24392 24392 24392
9 HP1   24391  8610  9596 24391 24391    24391  7987  8255
10 HP3   15633 15633 15633 15633 15633    15633 15633 15633", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

nulls_by_code %>% 
  pivot_longer(-code, names_to = "pollutant") %>% 
  group_by(pollutant) %>% 
  top_n(1, -value)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   pollutant [8]
#>   code  pollutant value
#>   <chr> <chr>     <int>
#> 1 BL0   so2        4933
#> 2 BQ7   o3          229
#> 3 BQ7   pm10_raw    310
#> 4 BQ8   pm10        323
#> 5 CR8   pm25        733
#> 6 HG4   nox         205
#> 7 HG4   no2         205
#> 8 HP3   co        15633
```

Comment: Thanks stefan. Please can you explain your solution?What does top_n(1, -value) do?

Comment: (: Sorry. `top_n` returns the top n rows (here the top 1) based on a column. If we want instead the bottom n rows with minimum values we can simply use -value. BTW: "value" is the name pivot_longer uses as default for the column containing the values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the help. Not sure why it's been downvoted already as I spent 3 hours trying to fix it myself before posting on StackOverflow. I thought this was a pretty tenacious effort! I will look into pivot_longer

Comment: Don't know either. I know myself that it's not easy to find the right answer on SO even it has probably already been answered. But don't worry about it. This happens sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the help stefan, and the kind words, I really appreciate it! I even tried a little humour in my post to make SO a more enjoyable place to be :0) Thanks for taking the time to answer