# Min and Max across multiple columns with NAs

Tags: r, max, min, na, inf

For the following sample data `dat`, is there a way to calculate `min` and `max` while handling `NA`s. My input is:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID  Name   PM      TP2   Sigma
                          1   Tim    1       2    3
                          2   Sam    0       NA   1
                          3   Pam    2       1    NA
                          4   Ali    1       0    2
                          NA  NA     NA      NA   NA
                          6   Tim    2       0    7", header = TRUE)
```

My required output is:

```
ID  Name  PM      TP2   Sigma  Min  Max
1    Tim  1       2    3       1    3
2    Sam  0       NA   1       0    1
3    Pam  2       1    NA      1    2
4    Ali  1       0    2       0    2
NA   NA   NA      NA   NA      NA   NA
6    Tim  2       0    7       0    7
```

**My Effort**

1- I have seen similar posts but none of them has discussed issues where all entries in a column were `NA`s e.g., [Get the min of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977353/get-the-min-of-two-columns)
Based on this, I have tried `pmin()` and `pmax()`, but they do not work for me.

2- Another similar question is [minimum (or maximum) value of each row across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193433/minimum-or-maximum-value-of-each-row-across-multiple-columns). Again, there is no need to handle `NA`s.

3- Lastly, this question [minimum (or maximum) value of each row across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193433/minimum-or-maximum-value-of-each-row-across-multiple-columns) talks about `NA` but not all elements in a column have missing values.

4- Also, some of the solutions require that the columns list to be included to be excluded is typed manually, my original data is quite `wide`, I want to have an easier solution where I can express columns by numbers rather than names.

**Partial Solution**

I have tried the following solution but `Min` column ends up having `Inf` and the `Max` column ends up having `-Inf`.

```
dat$min = apply(dat[,c(2:4)], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
dat$max = apply(dat[,c(2:4)], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I can manually get rid of `Inf` by using something like:

```
dat$min[is.infinite(dat$min)] = NA
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving my desired outcome? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `hablar`'s `min_` and `max_` function which returns `NA` if all values are `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min = min_(c_across(-ID)), 
         max = max_(c_across(-ID)))
```

You can also use this with `apply` -

```
cbind(dat, t(apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x) c(min = min_(x), max = max_(x)))))

#  ID PM TP2 Sigma min max
#1  1  1   2     3   1   3
#2  2  0  NA     1   0   1
#3  3  2   1    NA   1   2
#4  4  1   0     2   0   2
#5 NA NA  NA    NA  NA  NA
#6  5  2   0     7   0   7
```

Comment: Thank @Ronak Shah, would the first solution also require that I explicitly exclude all columns that should not be considered in decision making? Like the ```ID``` column above?

Could you also explain, what does c_across mean?

Comment: Yes, I have used `c_across(-ID)` to exclude `ID` from decision making. `c_across` is used along with `rowwise` to combine multiple columns together.

Comment: Any faster way where instead of writing column names, I could specify column numbers for exclusion and decision making?

Comment: Yes, `c_across(-1)` would work, so would `c_across(2:4)`

Answer (score 2):

On way might be to use `pmin` and `pmax` with `do.call`:

```
dat$min <- do.call(pmin, c(dat[,c(3:5)], na.rm=TRUE))
dat$max <- do.call(pmax, c(dat[,c(3:5)], na.rm=TRUE))
dat
#  ID Name PM TP2 Sigma min max
#1  1  Tim  1   2     3   1   3
#2  2  Sam  0  NA     1   0   1
#3  3  Pam  2   1    NA   1   2
#4  4  Ali  1   0     2   0   2
#5 NA <NA> NA  NA    NA  NA  NA
#6  6  Tim  2   0     7   0   7
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution seems to work with the `transform()` function:

```
dat <- transform(dat, min = pmin(PM, TP2, Sigma))
dat <- transform(dat, max = pmin(PM, TP2, Sigma))
```

Without using the `transform()` function, the data seemed to mess up. Also, the above command requires that all column names are written explicitly. I do not understand why writing a short version like below, fails.

```
pmin(dat[,2:4])) or
pmax(dat[,2:4]))
```

I am posting the only solution that I could come up with, in case someone else stumbles upon a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would use data.table for this task. I use the rowSums to count the numbers of row with na and compare it to the number of columns in total. I just use in dat.new all columns where you have at least one nonNA value. Then you can use the na.rm=T as usually.

I hope this little code helps you.

```
library(data.table)

#your data
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    PM      TP2   Sigma
                          1      1       2    3
                  2      0       NA   1
                  3      2       1    NA
                  4      1       0    2
                  NA     NA      NA   NA
                  5      2       0    7", header = TRUE)

#generate data.table and add id
dat <- data.table(dat)
number.cols <- dim(dat)[2] #4
dat[,id:=c(1:dim(dat)[1])]
# > dat
#     ID PM TP2 Sigma id
# 1:  1  1   2     3  1
# 2:  2  0  NA     1  2
# 3:  3  2   1    NA  3
# 4:  4  1   0     2  4
# 5: NA NA  NA    NA  5
# 6:  5  2   0     7  6

#use new data.table to select all rows with at least one nonNA value
dat.new <- dat[rowSums(is.na(dat))<number.cols,]
dat.new[, MINv:=min(.SD, na.rm=T), by=id]
dat.new[, MAXv:=max(.SD, na.rm=T), by=id]

#if you need it merged to the old data
dat <- merge(dat, dat.new[,.(id,MINv,MAXv)], by="id")
```